# How to hide div click button with asp.net validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

```
<div id="rgform" class="register_form">
            <label for="rg_form_name">Adınız</label><asp:TextBox ID="rg_form_name" CssClass="txtfld" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rg_form_name" ErrorMessage="Adınızı Giriniz" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <label for="rg_form_surname">Soyadınız</label><asp:TextBox ID="rg_form_surname" CssClass="txtfld" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rg_form_surname" ErrorMessage="Soyadınızı Giriniz" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <label for="rg_form_email">E-Posta</label><asp:TextBox ID="rg_form_email" CssClass="txtfld" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rg_form_email" ErrorMessage="E-Posta Giriniz" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rg_form_email" ErrorMessage="Geçerli Bir E-Posta Adresi Giriniz" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <br />
            <label for="rg_form_phone">Telefon</label><asp:TextBox ID="rg_form_phone" CssClass="txtfld" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rg_form_phone" ErrorMessage="Telefon Giriniz" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <label for="rg_form_address" style="vertical-align:top;">Adres</label><asp:TextBox ID="rg_form_address" CssClass="txtfld_multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox><br />
            <asp:Button ID="Register_Button" CssClass="register_button" runat="server" Text="Kayıt Ol" OnClick="Register_Button_Click" />
         </div>
       </div>

       <script>
           $('form').submit(function () {
               $('#rgform').hide();
           });

       </script>
```

When I click button,validation controls don't work  and form is submitted so,div hide.how to solve?

Comment: Did you check browser console for any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try return false if the form is invalid:

```
 $('form').submit(function () {
   var isValid = validateForm();
   if(isValid){
     $('#rgform').hide();
   }
   return isValid;
 });
```

Or if you want to hide the form no matter form is valid or not.

```
 $('form').submit(function () {
   var isValid = validateForm();
   $('#rgform').hide();
   return isValid;
 });
```

Comment: still dont work, now validation control is working but div dont hide

Comment: do you want to hide even though it success / fail?

Comment: I want to hide when you submit the form (success), but leave the fields blank when I click on the hidden div,so validation controls dont work

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit confusing. How can you click when the div is hidden?